# How to know all the documents in a topic has been consumed by a Kafka consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to write a Kafka consumer where in I an streaming all the documents that are in a topic. And I want to close the Kafka consumer once all the documents have been consumed and I don't have any other documents to consume.

Problem is since a consumer is supposed to continuously read and never stop, is there a way following which I can know that all the records in the Kafka topic has been consumed and committed so that I can close my consumer?

Comment: which client are you using?

Comment: For example, if you use confluent's python client, then you can know whether all the messages for a partition have been consumed by message.error().code() == confluent_kafka.KafkaError._PARTITION_EOF

Comment: I am using spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11 in my spark application.